# Show Iframe content which has iframe inside

Tags: javascript, java

I have a webpage which has a html document which is loaded inside an iframe, and the webpage is hosted in xxx url. This webpage is a java webpage. How can I render this xxx url in another webpage(javascript) using iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the publicly hosted URL of that webpage, use the following code and I guess it will work

```html
<iframe src="demo.html" name="iframe1"></iframe>

<p><a href="your url" target="iframe1">my page</a></p>
```

When you click on the link, it will open in the iframe